# Fetching the records of a cursor from a stored procedure

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, stored-procedures, amazon-redshift, plpgsql

I have created a stored procedure using cursor. I tried to fetch the record through cursor using **Fetch**. As **Fetch All** is not supported for  single cluster I mentioned **fetch next**.I am not getting any error and output as well.

Below is the code I have used. Could you let me know if I am doing something wrong.
I am doing in aws redshift . What should I do for the proper result.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_result1( result_set INOUT REFCURSOR ) AS 
$$
BEGIN
OPEN result_set FOR SELECT any_value(address_id) from address;
END;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

BEGIN;
CALL sp_result1( 'result' );
FETCH next FROM result;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct.  If you post the error you are seeing it would help narrow down what is happening.

That said I have a few ideas for you.  One way this could be erroring is your transaction is ending (unexpectedly).  This could be the case if your session connection is in "auto-commit" mode.  Is the error you are getting about the cursor not existing?  Check the settings of your workbench (or whatever you are using to connect to Redshift).

You can also check the XIDs of the statements to see if they are being run in the same transaction block.  The system table SVL_STATEMENTTEXT contains the XID for every command you are sending Redshift and you can use your PID (session ID) to find just your commands.  You can use "SELECT pg_backend_pid();" to find your PID.

If all of your commands are in the same transaction block (same XID), I recommend creating your cursor and fetching from it outside of the stored procedure.  The query may have an error or is failing for some other reason (again error message would help). You can set up the cursor using a DECLARE statement and then FETCH from it.  If this works then your query isn't the issue.

If all of that looks good then definitely post the error message.  You may also want to set up a test case with a dummy table that reproduces the issue so that others can experience what you are seeing.